# Decoding response with mixed UTF-8 encoding in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, unicode, utf-8

I'm downloading data from a website using aiohttp and I'm getting a bytes object as a response but I'm having an hard time decoding it.
This is an example of the reponse I get

```
b'\\r\\nLocalit\xc3\xa0' # Località
b'\\u003cdiv\\u003e12/09/2019\\u003c/div\\u003e\\r\\n' # <div>12/09/2019</div>
```

From what I understand it has normal unicode for text and escaped unicode for the html tags and line feed.
If I try to decode it using "str(content, "utf-8")" I still have the html tags in this format

```
\u003cdiv \u003e12/09/2019\u003c/div\u003e\r\n
```

Should I just do a manual `.replace("\u003", "<")` for every tag or is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `'unicode-escape'` [codec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#module-codecs) to convert the unicode part, then reencode transparently to bytes (latin-1 is convenient for this, as is provides a 1-to-1 correspondance between bytes and chars), then decode as 'utf-8':

```
b = b'\\u003cdiv\\u003e12/09/2019\\u003c/div\\u003e\\r\\n\\r\\nLocalit\xc3\xa0'
b.decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
# '<div>12/09/2019</div>\r\n\r\nLocalità'
```

Comment: If I use `unicode-escape` on the text i get `LocalitÃ` instead of `Località`

Comment: Sorry, I had missed that part, I edited the answer!